# ¿Como puedo almacenar datos de un datagridview a una base de datos en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo un datagridview que se llena con los datos de alumnos de acuerdo a una busqueda realizada a traves de un combobox precargado con talleres en los cuales los alumnos se registran.
Mi duda es: ¿Como puedo insertar solo campos especificos del datagridview a la base de datos?

Anexo el codigo que tengo en el botón de guardar y efectivamente almacena al ser presionado por primera vez, posteriormente cierra la ventana y cuando quiero agregar nuevos registros ejecutando esa acción por medio del mismo boton, los registros de idregistro son enviados como 'NULL'.

Nota: Esto solo ocurre cada dos veces (un registro se envia correctamente, el siguiente se envia como NULL, el siguiente correctamente, el siguiente como NULL)

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click

    Try
        cmCon = New MySqlCommand
        adCon.Open()
        cmCon.Connection = adCon
        ''Dim query As String = "Insert into asistencia (fecha, tipoasistencia, idregistro) values(@fecha, @tipoasistencia, @idregistro)"

        cmCon.CommandText = "Call spInsAsistencia(@fecha, @tipoasistencia, @idregistro)"

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAsistencia.Rows
            cmCon.Parameters.Clear()
            cmCon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", FormatoFecha(dtpFecha.Value))
            cmCon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoasistencia", CStr(row.Cells(0).Value))
            cmCon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idregistro", CStr(row.Cells(1).Value))

            cmCon.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Next

        MsgBox("Guardado correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Información")
        frmAsistencias.ActualizarGrid()



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        adCon.Close()
        Me.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

primero inicia comentando el cierre del formulario

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click

    Try
        cmCon = New MySqlCommand
        adCon.Open()
        cmCon.Connection = adCon
        ''Dim query As String = "Insert into asistencia (fecha, tipoasistencia, idregistro) values(@fecha, @tipoasistencia, @idregistro)"

        cmCon.CommandText = "Call spInsAsistencia(@fecha, @tipoasistencia, @idregistro)"

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAsistencia.Rows
            cmCon.Parameters.Clear()
            cmCon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", FormatoFecha(dtpFecha.Value))
            cmCon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoasistencia", CStr(row.Cells(0).Value))
            cmCon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idregistro", CStr(row.Cells(1).Value))

            cmCon.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Next

        MsgBox("Guardado correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Información")
        frmAsistencias.ActualizarGrid()

        adCon.close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        adCon.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

prueba con eso , suerte